# how to sort matrix of lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

So basically I have 5 2d lists and these lists contain `rate` and `deviation`. Like this
[image]

So in this file, you can see a total of 16 rates and dev for each list. Basically rate and dev are combined to form one unit and there are 16 units like this each list. I want to form a 4x5 matrix of rate from all the list and sort the whole matrix in descending order and get the first 4 highest rates from it and get their respective `dev`. The first matrix will contain the first 4 rates of `Rate1`, `Rate2`, `Rate3`, `Rate4` and `Rate5`: like this

```
16 6 5 6 0   0 5 2 0 0   16 8 8 9 10   0 7 6 6 6
16 6 4 5 0   0 5 0 0 0   16 7 8 9 9    0 7 6 6 6
16 6 3 2 0   0 5 0 0 0   0  7 8 9 8    0 6 6 5 6
0  5 2 0 0   0 5 0 0 0   0  7 8 7 7    0 6 5 5 2
```

After sorting all these matrices, the expected output will look like this:

```
from 1st matrix: 
[16,16,16,6] = rates
[7,2,10,26] = Dev

from 2nd matrix: 
[5,5,5,5] = rates
[17,8,14,26] = dev

from 3rd matrix: 
[16,16,10,9] = rates
[12,7,90,49] = dev

from 4th matrix: 
[7,7,6,6] = rates
[53,30,48,37] = dev

combined result:
[16,16,16,6,5,5,5,5,16,16,10,9,7,7,6,5] = rates
[7,2,10,26,12,7,90,49,53,30,48,37,53,30,48,37] = dev
```

My attempt:

```
rate1 = [16,16,16,0,0,0,0,0,16,16,0,0,0,0,0,0]
rate2 = [6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,8,7,7,7,7,7,6,6]
rate3 = [5,4,3,2,2,0,0,0,8,8,8,8,6,6,6,5]
rate4 = [6,5,2,0,0,0,0,0,9,9,9,7,6,6,5,5]
rate5 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,9,8,7,6,6,6,2]

dev1 = [7,2,10,-8,-1,-5,-4,-26,12,7,-14,-21,-16,-15,-19,-20]
dev2 = [26,19,22,18,17,8,14,26,15,21,29,49,53,30,48,37]
dev3 = [53,54,40,36,57,-8,-1,-5,49,53,48,37,44,90,45,88]
dev4 = [53,54,57,-8,-1,-5,-4,-26,49,53,48,90,88,55,61,53]
dev5 = [-8,-1,-5,-4,-26,-25,-16,0,90,88,61,79,63,88,82,92]
import itertools
from itertools import chain
price1 = list(zip(rate1, dev1))
price2 = list(zip(rate2, dev2))
price3 = list(zip(rate3, dev3))
price4 = list(zip(rate4, dev4))
price5 = list(zip(rate5, dev5))

newPrice1 = [sorted(block, reverse=True) for block in price1]
newPrice2 = [sorted(block, reverse=True) for block in price2]
newPrice3 = [sorted(block, reverse=True) for block in price3]
newPrice4 = [sorted(block, reverse=True) for block in price4]
newPrice5 = [sorted(block, reverse=True) for block in price5]
```

This will just sort a single list at a time. But I want to consider the whole as mentioned above. I don't know the right approach. Can someone please help?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: I have made some changes, can you look at it?